# What contributes to negative emotion / sentiment in this example?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have got the following text labelled as negative. Could you please point to what would (lexically, syntactically) contribute to negative emotion here? Is it sarcastic in any way?

> #LE CREUSET#全球獨家發售首個粉紫色花形琺瑯鑄鐵鍋-只限於國泰航空之「非凡精選」府上送貨服務中獨家發售

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that "非凡精選" is ironic because the "粉紫色花形琺瑯鑄鐵鍋" is a stupid thing.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by labeled as negative.  Is this a label you put on the text, or did some other source label it for you?

Comment: @Colin McLarty It was labeled by some other source (human). I would like to teach the machine to do the same.

Comment: You should ask the human to clarify this labeling.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty unfourtunately I don't have access to the source anymore.

Comment: @D_K then you shouldn't teach the machine to consider it "negative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text seems to describe this pot:

[image]

I have to second Ringil's suggestion that your source considers such pots stupid, and so the source takes the text to be sarcastic.  It is a semantic issue rather than lexical or syntactic.

Comment: Thanks for the picture, tells more than a thousand words. I sensed it is semantically sarcastic, but really your explanation makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

One way of using quotation mark is to indicate special meaning, which can be "to mean the opposite", sarcastic.

Another way of using quotation mark is to emphasis.

The text wanted to emphasis and your machine might have taken it to mean "the opposite"

Comment: agree & and that is why sarcasm is truly hard topic of AI / sentiment analysis.